# Can I create a Pivot Cache in VBA using non-contiguous rows?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to create a pivot table, but cannot include the rows which are subcomponents of a parent row. Can I simply exclude these rows from the pivotcache, or should I find a different way to go about this? That is: is it possible to create a pivot table using a cache of non-contiguous rows? Here's what I've got, though it gives me an error (Invalid Procedure or Call to Argument):

```
Dim FLF As WorkSheet
Set FLF = Workbooks("Template.xlsx").Worksheets("Template")
Dim TotalQQSheet As Worksheet
Set TotalQQSheet = Workbooks("Template.xlsx").Worksheets("Total QQ Sheet")

Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim QQDataRange As Range
Dim NewCacheAddress As String

Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

'Finding the range of the PivotCache and ensuring subcomponents aren't included for the TotalQQSheet.
'Subcomponent composition (to be excluded) is listed in italic.

With FLF
    Set QQDataRange = .Range("A7:K7")
    For x = 7 To lng
        If .Range("K" & x).Font.FontStyle <> "Italic" And .Range("K" & x).Value > 0 Then
            Set QQDataRange = Union(QQDataRange, .Range("A" & x & ":K" & x))
        End If
    Next x
End With

Set pvt = TotalQQSheet.PivotTables("TotalQQTable")
TotalQQSheet.Activate

With pvt

pvt.ClearTable

NewCacheAddress = FLF.Name & "!" & _
    QQDataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Error here
.ChangePivotCache _
    Workbooks("Template.xlsx").PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=NewCacheAddress)

.RefreshTable

End With
```

Comment: If you can't do this manually, you can't do it with VBA. Perhaps add a flag to the rows you do want to use and just use that as a filter in your pivot table.

Comment: Just create the `PivotTable` using range `A7:K?` (?=last row of data), then filter the `PivotTable` by Field `K` criteria: "> 0"

Comment: For some reason, when I do that I still get the error. Weird. Must be my syntax.

Comment: Never mind, got it. I'd forgotten to throw in the header rows. Thanks everyone.